# How to store point data (height) for each point in a linestring in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, gpx

I am reading GPX files into OpenLayers. I would like to be able to save the edited route back to GPX including the height and time information that the original file contained (or use SRTM data to fill in new elevations). Is there an easy way to do this or is it going to be create a geometry.point to store each vertex of my linestring?

Thanks in advance,
Jon

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen, no geospatial format really allows for pointalines, though they'd be plenty useful. You'll probably have to have two parallel datastructures, for the line and constituent points.